# Adding dynamic data to Redux Toolkit's createApi from React Native Text Input?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Newer developer here. I've been stuck on this for far too long now and running out of places to turn!

Tech:
React Native
Redux Toolkit

I'm trying to take data from a Text Input on RN and add it to my RTK createApi call.

[RTK website](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi) shows this:

```
export const pokemonApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'pokemonApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPokemonByName: builder.query({
      query: (name) => `pokemon/${name}`,
    }),
  }),
})
```

I was hoping I could do something similar instead of ${name} being dynamic it would be my text input data? Has anyone seen examples of this? does the data have to hit a slice first then the API? Do I need createAsyncThunk?

trying not to be too verbose here is what I have so far. data is coming into the slice, but not sure where to go from there?

electedApi.js (API call)

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getAddress } from '../../services/slices/addressSlice';

export const electedsApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'newsApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'baseurl.help.com',
  }),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getElectedByAddress: builder.query({
      const { address } = useSelector(state => state.address);
      query: address => `${address}`,
    }),
  }),
});
```

addressSlice.js (state)

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  address: '',
};

export const addressSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'address',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getAddress: (state, action) => {
      state.address = action.payload;
      console.log(state.address + 'from slice');
    },
  },
});
export const { getAddress } = addressSlice.actions;

export default addressSlice.reducer;
```

Landing.js (form input)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, Image, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getAddress } from '../../services/slices/addressSlice';

export default function Landing({ navigation }) {
  const [text, setText] = useState();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handlePress = () => {
    if (!text) {
      Alert.alert('please enter address');
      setText('');
    } else {
      Alert.alert('thanks');
      dispatch(getAddress(text));
      setText('');
      navigation.navigate('Main');
    }
  };
  return (
      <TextInput
        placeholderStyle={styles.input}
        placeholder="your address"
        onChangeText={text => setText(text)}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={handlePress}>
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your query endpoint cannot access state and should also not do so. RTK-Q determines that a new request should be made when the input to the hook changes - in your case there would be no input change and so a new request would never be made.

Just use it like this:

```js
const address = useSelector(state => state.address.address)
const result = useGetElectedByAddressQuert(address)
```